# Boolean conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can't understand how I possibly can check value given in function. All my known methods fails. Sorry for lame question!:)

```
# doesn't work, but should to
window.mobilecheck = function() {
    return true;
}
if (window.mobilecheck==true) {
    alert('true');
}

# works, but shouldn't
window.mobilecheck = function() {
    return false;
}
if (window.mobilecheck) {
    alert('true');
}

# doesn't work, but should
window.mobilecheck = function() {
    return 1;
}
if (window.mobilecheck==1) {
    alert('true');
}
```

So how to check if function returns true or false if this doesn't work?

Comment: window.mobilecheck() == 1 ?. Execute your function, in current way any `if` will be true, as function exists

Comment: [Calling functions - MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions)

Comment: thanks guys. But how to check what function returns? There are no answer in this link :(

Comment: @Gediminas: scroll down and **read** it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_expressions

Comment: "But how to check what function returns ?" - execute it :) you will get that result of what is written after `return` operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `window.mobilecheck` you get the function, not the evaluation/return value of the function. Use to `window.mobilecheck() ==1` to evaluate your function.

Comment: Sorry. I did not see your comment. I changed the answer two a "community wiki answer".